# Is there a way to get back to your application from the settings page of iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I have designed an app where the app needs to enable the GPS. There is a page for the user which ask use GPS? To this answer there are 2 options YES and NO. Now my concern is when user clicks on YES he should be directed to settings page and that part is done but now after enabling the GPS from this page the user should redirect to the app again but unfortunately there is no way as there is no back button in the setting page.. Please suggest what I can do in this regards?

Comment: I am afraid, but there is no way back. When you open native Setting app, your app goes in background.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to open your app (aside from user tap your app or a related notification) is to do some custom url handling. but unfortunately you can't do such a thing. The other thing you can try is to:

1. Setup a background thread when your app goes to background
2. check for location service availability
3. if it changed to your desired value, open a custom url which in turn will open your app (you should register for hat particular url in your `info.plist` and such)

but There are some things to keep in mind:

- Such Behavior will almost surely get your app rejected by Apple.
- in iOS 9+ Apple added a new feature that will help you in this particular problem. when an app gets opened from another app (settings.app for you here) it will add a `Back to xxxx` in place for network indicator to help user get back were he was.

So, IMHO leave the user experience be as it is for all other applications and don't worry about how he would get back to your app.